# Meaning in context: through yield, return 15%, etc

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, prepositions, verbs

> “Fundamentals matter less in an environment like this,” said Orlando Green, a fixed-income strategist at Credit Agricole SA’s corporate and investment banking unit in London. “It’s very much driven by circumstance. Investors are looking for where they can pick up a little extra return **through yield**. You’ve seen that with Portugal having rallied despite everything that’s been going on.”
>
> French 10-year yields slid seven basis points, or 0.07 percentage point, this week to 1.57 percent at the 5 p.m. close in London. They dropped to 1.562 percent today, the least since Bloomberg began collecting the data in 1990. **The 1.75 percent security due November 2024 rose 0.63, or 6.30 euros per 1,000-euro ($1,351) face amount, to 101.66**. The rate was little changed today.
> ...
> The benchmark German 10-year yield declined five basis points in the week to 1.16 percent, ending the trading day yesterday at a record-low 1.15 percent. The rate on similar- maturity Portuguese debt fell 20 basis points, the biggest weekly drop since the five days through April 18.
>
> Portuguese government securities **returned 15 percent** this year through yesterday, the best-performing euro-area sovereign debt market after Greece, according to Bloomberg World Bond Indexes. Their French peers gained 6.8 percent and Germany’s rose 5.5 percent.
>
> -- *French Yields Fall to Records With Bunds’ on Ukraine Safety Bid* [Link](http://www.garp.org/risk-news-and-resources/risk-headlines/story.aspx?newsId=114720)

How do I understand **through yield**?

And the second bold sentence sounds a bit weird to me. How could the security rise 0.63 to 101.66? Does it mean the original price of the security with the yield of 1.75% was 101.03 euros and rose 0.63 euro per face value of 100 euros?

Does the **returned** here mean **yielded a return of 15%** or **prices rebounded by 15%**?

Comment: It's bond investment here, so I think it means _by way of coupon payment_. @DamkerngT.

Comment: In the context of stock investment, *yield* usually means *dividend yield*. My guess (which could be wrong) is that if the 1.75% security face value is 100 euros, it's now 101.66, raised from 101.03. As for the "returned 15 percent" of securities, I believe that it's about the price gains plus dividend yields (and any other kinds of yields, if exist) that was 15% in total.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I thought so, but this didn't quite match the last sentence in which *gained* and *rose* were used. Thus, I considered another possibility.

Comment: I'm not sure about their jargon either. As far as I can tell, *gain* is more related to the price (or market price). In this context, it seems like *gained* and *rose* are both amount to the same thing.

Comment: They mean the same thing, but neither of the words are jargon. I suspect **return** here is synonymous with **rally**. @DamkerngT.

Comment: Quite possibly. If we take that both *return* and *rally* could mean "an increase in the value of something after a period when its value has been low". I've noticed that sometimes financial writers include other yields into the returns besides the price gains. In my humble opinion, these are jargon because as we are experiencing it, it's unclear what precisely they meant, though we have *some* ideas about what they wrote. (When I said "financial writers", I didn't only think of English, I've seen that in my first language too.)

Answer (score 1):

> Investors are looking for where they can pick up a little extra return **through yield**.

Read *through* as *via* or *by way of*. *Yield* refers to the percentage of gain made on principal when purchasing bonds. This is talking about the current behavior of fixed income investors: they're looking to buy bonds which give higher rates of return, even at the cost of increased risk or lowered stability (*fundamentals matter less in an environment like this*). They buy bonds because stocks are much more volatile and riskier; bonds offer a "guaranteed" rate of return. Because the investors are on a fixed income, they want safer plays, preferring security over the possibility of large profits.

> And the second bold sentence sounds a bit weird to me. How could the security rise 0.63 to 101.66? Does it mean the original price of the security with the yield of 1.75% was 101.03 euros and rose 0.63 euro per face value of 100 euros?

The second bolded sentence means that the price of the 1.75% security has effectively gone up, though the pricing scheme is quite complicated. 101.66 is above the [par value](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/parvalue.asp) (which is 100) of the security. This means that the 1.75% item is trading at a premium, because it's priced over its par value, and is now 0.63 units more expensive than it was previously. Generally speaking, when interest rates fall, as mentioned at the start of the paragraph, bond prices rise.

> Portuguese government securities returned 15 percent this year through yesterday
>   Does the returned here mean yielded a return of 15% or prices rebounded by 15%?

It means they *yielded a return of 15%* over the past year, [as calculated by Bloomberg](http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/BPOR:IND). Talk of an investment's *return* is almost always referring to the yield, profit, etc.; we generally don't use *return* to speak of price increases in terms of percentages. *Rebound* or *rise* are the words of choice for that situation. If *rising to a previously held price level* is meant, you can expect an explicit mention of pricing to follow *return*; e.g. *a return to a price of X*.

Comment: I think par value (face value) is fixed at 100 euros. Only the market price would change.

Comment: You're right, I've misused the term. Edited.